# Getting NextAuth.js user session in Apollo Server context

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-server, next-auth

My web app is using:

- NextJS
- NextAuth.js
- Apollo Server

I have a NextAuth set up in my app, and I am able to log in just fine.

The problem is coming from trying to get access to the user's session in the Apollo context. I want to pass my user's session into every resolver. Here's my current code:

```
import { ApolloServer, AuthenticationError } from "apollo-server-micro";
import schema from "./schema";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dataloaders from "./dataloaders";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/client";

let db;

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    /*
    ...

    database connection setup
    
    ...
    */

    // get user's session
    const userSession = await getSession({ req });
    console.log("USER SESSION", userSession); // <-- userSession is ALWAYS null


    if (!userSession) {
      throw new AuthenticationError("User is not logged in.");
    }

    return { db, dataloaders, userSession };
  },
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default apolloServer.createHandler({ path: "/api/graphql" });
```

The problem is, the session (`userSession`) is always null, even if I am logged in (and can get a session just fine from a proper NextJS API route). My guess is that because the NextAuth function used to get the session, `getSession({ req })` is being passed `req`--which is provided from Apollo Server Micro, and not from NextJS (which NextAuth is expecting). I've done a lot of searching and can't find anyone who's had this same problem. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If anyone happens upon this with using Auth0 + graphql:

import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0'

  context: async args => {
    const session = await getSession(args.req)
    return { user: session.user }
  }

Comment: So perhaps did you try not passing `req` as an object, but directly? `const userSession = await getSession( req )`

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly this issue and I found it was because of the Apollo GraphQL playground.

The playground does not send credentials without `"request.credentials": "include"`.

My NextAuth / GraphQL API looks like this:

```js
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-micro";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/client";
import { typeDefs, resolvers } "./defined-elsewhere"

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    return { session };
  },
  playground: {
    settings: {
      "editor.theme": "light",
      "request.credentials": "include",
    },
  },
});
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: do you mind share your full code? I still not able to get req. Do you set any option when `.createHandler`?

Comment: I would still like to find a way to use `getServerSession` here instead of `getSession`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into something similar.  I'm not 100% sure because it's hard to know the exact details since your example code above doesn't show how you're interacting with apollo from the client *before* the session is coming through as null. I believe however that you're probably making an API call from inside the `getStaticProps` which causes static code generation and gets run at *build time* - ie when no such user context / session could possibly exist.

See https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/383

`The getStaticProps method in Next.js is only for build time page generation (e.g. for generating static pages from a headless CMS) and cannot be used for user specific data such as sessions or CSRF Tokens.`

Also fwiw I'm not sure why you got downvoted - seems like a legit question to ask imo even if the answer is mostly a standard rtm :). Has happened to me here before too - you win some you lose some :) Cheers

Comment: Hey, thanks! I wasn't expecting to get an answer :) I will investigate a little further with this in mind and report back.

Comment: No worries - I hope it's helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get the session information of the currently logged in user in my `ApolloServer context` but was getting null as response from the `getSession()` function. So, I created my own function to basically get the session data from my NextAuth endpoint form the apollo server context.

`src/index.ts`

```
context: async ({ req }): Promise<GraphQLContext> => {
  const session = await getServerSession(req.headers.cookie);
  return { session: session as Session, prisma };
}
```

`getServerSession.ts`

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

export const getServerSession = async (cookie: string) => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost/api/auth/session',{
    headers: { cookie: cookie },
  });
  const session = await res.json();
  return session;
};
```

I hope this helps everyone who is trying to get the session information in apollo server context while using next-auth for authentication purposes.