# Having trouble getting next-auth user session in gql context

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, next-auth

The answers provided in this post didn't work for me, and there's been no update.
[Getting NextAuth.js user session in Apollo Server context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800495/getting-nextauth-js-user-session-in-apollo-server-context)

```js
// ./graphql/context.ts
/**
 * Populates a context object for use in resolvers.
 * If there is a valid session from next-auth, find the user and add them to context
 * @param context context from apollo server
 */
type ApolloApiContext = ApolloContext < {
  req: IncomingMessage
} > ;
export async function createContext(context: ApolloApiContext): Promise < Context > {
  const session = await getSession(context); // ALWAYS null
  let user: User | null = null;
  if (session?.user?.email) {
    user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email: session.user.email } });
   }
  return {
    db: prisma,
    prisma,
    user,
  };
}
```

I'm guessing there's a mismatch between what Next v Apollo are expecting from requests. Any ideas how to get a valid next-auth session into gql context?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

const session = await getSession({ req: context.req });

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution I came across is calling the

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session
```

endpoint separately and extracting the session. You can find the full version [on this UR](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3803)L. Scroll down to the last one, by @gaganbiswas